# Flutter - Fetch image from a page that it's RSS does not have image tag

Tags: flutter, dart, rss

I'm coding a RSS reader project . I can get RSS and all it's items and I can show all of them in screen. but some RSS doesn't have image or media or enclosure or any other tag that contain image URL. these RSS contain links of some pages . How can I fetch that pages image ? this pages are from news websites

Now I'm showing an asset image for RSS that doesn't have image tag

Answer (score -2):

If an RSS feed doesn't provide an image URL within its items, and instead contains links to pages on news websites, you can fetch the page content and extract the image from there. Here's a general approach you can take using Flutter and Dart:

Use a package like http or dio to make an HTTP request to the page URL obtained from the RSS feed.
Once you receive the response, you can parse the HTML content using a package like html or flutter_html to extract the image URL. The exact method for extracting the image will depend on the structure of the HTML page.
Once you have the image URL, you can use a package like cached_network_image or flutter_image to display the image in your Flutter app.
Here's an example implementation using the http and html packages:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;

class RSSReader extends StatefulWidget {
  final String rssFeedUrl;

  RSSReader({required this.rssFeedUrl});

  @override
  _RSSReaderState createState() => _RSSReaderState();
}

class _RSSReaderState extends State<RSSReader> {
  String? imageUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchImageFromPage();
  }

  void fetchImageFromPage() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(widget.rssFeedUrl));
      final document = parser.parse(response.body);
      final imgElement = document.querySelector('img'); // Replace with the appropriate CSS selector for the image

      if (imgElement != null) {
        setState(() {
          imageUrl = imgElement.attributes['src'];
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching image: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return imageUrl != null
        ? Image.network(imageUrl!) // Show the fetched image
        : Image.asset('assets/placeholder_image.png'); // Show a placeholder image
  }
}
```

In this example, the RSSReader widget takes an rssFeedUrl parameter, which should be the URL of the RSS feed item that doesn't contain an image URL. The fetchImageFromPage function makes an HTTP request to the page URL, parses the HTML content, and extracts the image URL using a CSS selector (img in this example). If an image URL is found, it is stored in the imageUrl variable, which triggers a rebuild of the widget to display the fetched image. If no image URL is found, a placeholder image is shown instead.

Make sure to replace 'assets/placeholder_image.png' with the actual asset path of your placeholder image in your project.

Remember to include the necessary dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.3
  html: ^0.15.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  flutter_image: ^2.1.0
```

This example provides a starting point for fetching images from web pages associated with RSS feeds that don't provide direct image URLs. You may need to modify the CSS selector or adjust the image extraction logic based on the specific structure of the pages you are dealing with.

Comment: wow great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get any of this from chatgpt? (it's so awesome)